# Properly binding values changed in an AngularJS service to the view

Tags: angularjs, data-binding

I have a "click" function associated with an OpenLayers custom service. The details are not important, but I basically generate a JSON object when a vector on the map has been clicked. The vector is exposed through the service (which is called by a custom directive).

My question is this. How is the best (tidiest) way to bind the property exposed through the service, and called through a directive, to a value in my ng-view? Sample code below.

```
<h2>My Map</h2>
<p>A: {{selected.a}}</p> <!--This is what I want to do... -->
<p>B: {{selected.b}}</p> <!--This is what I want to do... -->
<p>C: {{selected.c}}</p> <!--This is what I want to do... -->
<div map-dir id="map" class="map"></div>

<script>
angular.module("app")
.controller("MainController", function($scope, openlayers){
    openlayers.init();

    /*
     * Needs to update the $scope whenever openlayers.selected
     * changes (could be any time after init())
     */
    $scope.selected = openlayers.selected;
})
.service("openlayers", function(){

    //Do some stuff

    var activeVector = {a: null, b: null, c: null};

    //Function called whenever a user clicks on a map
    function updateActiveVector(a,b,c){
        activeVector = {a: a, b: b, c: c};
    }

    return {
        init: init,
        selected: activeVector
    };

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controllers!  This is exactly the job they were born for.  Just add a dependency to the service in the controller you have, and then add the return from the "openlayers" service to the scope of the controller

so

```
.controller("MainController", function($scope){
    //Do something
})
```

would become

```
.controller("MainController", function($scope, openlayers){
    $scope.selected = openlayers.selected;
})
```

You also have to add the controller to the page, so you would also have to update the html from

```
<h2>My Map</h2>
<p>Name: {{selected.name}}</p> <!--This is what I want to do... -->
<div map-dir id="map" class="map"></div>
```

to something like

```
<h2>My Map</h2>
<div ng-controller="MainController">
<p>Name: {{selected.name}}</p> <!--This is what I want to do... -->
</div>
<div map-dir id="map" class="map"></div>
```

This should then show the binding you were hoping for.

Comment: I had tried that before and it "wasn't working", but I just tried again and changed it from `{{selected.name}}` to `{{selected}}` and it printed this to the screen: `{name: null}`... So it was working all along I just didn't realise it was printing a null value! Don't I feel stupid...

Comment: What is the value of activeVector?  we're assuming it's an object when it's being assigned to 'selected', with a name property, but perhaps it's a string?

Comment: ah, that explains it :)

Comment: Do the controller and directive both then point to the same "instance" of `openlayers` then? I can't for the life of me figure out why the values are null... They are being changed from within the directive and accessed from the controller.

Comment: Yes, there should only be once instance of the openlayers service that will then be shared between the controller and the directive.  Are you sure that the openlayers.init() call is actually executing?  I've never seen a link declaration like that before....maybe instead of calling the init() method from the directive, call it from the controller instead?

Comment: Yes it is - the map itself is working perfectly fine and all of the values in the service are being set properly they are just out of scope of the controller.

Comment: In the directive, after you change the value of the scope variable, call scope.$digest();  this should inform the controller that the value has changed and update the view bindings

Comment: The value of the scope variable is changed in the service - I am trying to bind a service property to the controller's scope. For now I have removed the directive and am just doing `openlayers.init(); $scope.selected = openlayers.selected;` and it's still not updating the UI!

Comment: what do you get if you console log the openlayers.selected in the controller, just before you assign it to the scope?

Comment: `{name: null}` which is what it should be when the init() finishes, so that is correct

Comment: I see, so is the service init method doing some extra processing after it has returned? In truth, I don't know how angular will do the updates on things in the services. Ordinarily, I would get the controller to ask the service to do something, and then update the controller with the result when it's done, usually  via a promise, which then would update the view with the new value.

Comment: Can we do the same here, so that the controller binds to the value when its been properly initialised. So would it be possible the get the init method to return a promise, then in the controller, assign the $scope.selected in the 'then' of the 'init's promise?

Comment: I am trying that now... But I don't see how it will work? If I am returning `{init: init, selected: (function() { return selected; } ) }` then when the value `selected` is updated from the service will the controller have the updated version? This happens any time the user clicks on a marker on a map so could be seconds or minutes after the function has returned the promise.

Comment: I have updated the code again to best explain what I want to do and simplify it a little... The interface is displaying `null` for all three values even though they are being changed inside the service (I have checked).

Comment: Hi Josh, while you were updating your post, I was trying to put a plunkr together with the existing example.  The link to it is http://plnkr.co/edit/aEHWrFENZBAjaWDpQpCx?p=preview please take a look to see if it would do what you were trying to achieve.  I'll take a look at your update now....

Comment: I think the key point from my example, is that the value is updated on the activeVector object (in the service) directly; the whole object is not being replaced.  I think if the whole object were replaced, i.e activeVector = {}, then the binding between the controller (and thus the view), would no longer be active...

Comment: just to clarify, I have just tested the updating of the values of the object as opposed to updating the whole object, and my assumption was correct.  From the plunkr, if I change the line     activeVector.name = updatedName; to     activeVector = {name: updatedName}; then the scope no loger gets updated with the name change.

Comment: Yeah I understood what you meant. I added $scope.$apply() to the code and it's working now... Not sure how "correct" it is to use that though! Cheers for your help mate.